# Parsing date string in Java of format [2012-07-15T20:55:33+00:00]

Tags: java, android

Im trying to parse a String thats a date  "2012-07-15T20:55:33+00:00", however I keep getting illegal argument exception. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddzHH:mm:SS+00:00"); 
String date = "2012-07-15T20:55:33+00:00";
Log.e("res",sdf.format(date));
```

Throws

```
    07-15 12:37:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(20985): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 12:37:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(20985): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
07-15 12:37:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(20985):    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:365)
07-15 12:37:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(20985):    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
```

Comment: But you do realize, that `E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss` defines completely different format than the one used for your date string?

Comment: Yup, My understanding of date format was completely wrong. I fixed it in the original question now, but still get that error.

Comment: You've got `z` between `dd` and `HH` in your `SimpleDateFormat` but your `date` has `T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use sdf.parse(date, new ParsePosition(0)) instead of sdf.format(date).

Comment: Hey that doesn't throw an error anymore. But it does give me null.  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddzHH:mm:SS"); 
String date = "2012-07-15T20:55:33+00:00";
Log.e("res",sdf.parse(date,new ParsePosition(0))+"  ");

Comment: try SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSz")

Comment: don' forget to add z at the end to take time zone into account.  I edited my previous comment.

Comment: Hey, that worked perfectly, I just had to make the :SS lowercase though. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you use below code and it will work like a charm.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"); 
Date date = new Date();
Log.d("res",sdf.format(date));
```

You can set a date in date object like `date.setMonth(month);`... etc.. and sdf.format will return String date in desired format.

Comment: Yes, this will work like a charm but I want to parse my date string.